# Is it necessary to have synchronization over list which will be accessed only for remove operation

Tags: java, multithreading, linked-list

I have a `LinkedList` already initialized with some objects. Now elements will be removed from the `head` of this `linkedlist` from multiple threads. It doesn't matter which thread gets what element as long as no thread gets any duplicate element. I wonder whether is it necessary for me to synchronize over this list so the removal is sequential or do I need to use any Concurrent variant of List. Note only `linkedlist.poll()` method will be called from other threads. To test it I wrote one test also in which I have a list of integers and from multiple threads i take few integers and add them. Then when all the threads are done I assert that the total sum of integers that list had is equal to the sum of all sums returned by those threads. For me it never fails without synchronization, so is my assumption correct or is there a fault in my test ?

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Demo {

    private final LinkedList<Integer> list;
    private static final int THREAD_COUNT = 5;
    private static final int LIST_SIZE = 250;

    public Demo(){
        list = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, LIST_SIZE)
                .collect(LinkedList::new, LinkedList::add, LinkedList::addAll);
    }

    private final static BiFunction<Demo, CountDownLatch, Callable<Integer>> callableFactory = (demo, latch) -> () -> {
        try {
            System.out.println("Here "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
            latch.countDown();
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Running task on thread "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, LIST_SIZE / THREAD_COUNT)
                .map(x -> demo.getNumber())
                .sum();
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        if(LIST_SIZE < THREAD_COUNT || LIST_SIZE % THREAD_COUNT != 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong parameters to test");
        ExecutorService exe = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_COUNT);
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(THREAD_COUNT);
        Demo d = new Demo();
        List<Future<Integer>> futures = exe.invokeAll(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, THREAD_COUNT).mapToObj(x-> callableFactory.apply(d, latch)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        System.out.println("Tasks submitted");
        int sum = 0;
        for(Iterator<Future<Integer>> itr = futures.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); sum+=itr.next().get());
        System.out.println(sum);
        System.out.println(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, LIST_SIZE).sum());
        exe.shutdownNow();
    }

    public int getNumber(){
        return list.poll();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are probably confusing removal and read-only access. Read-only access from multiple threads is usually fine as long as the objects are *correctly published* (unless the object internally does some modifications on read-only access, in which case it is not really "read-only" anymore). As soon as you start any kind of modifications, you have to use-thread safe stuff.

Comment: i do have a sort of feeling that it can happen that same head is removed from multiple threads !

Comment: you should not rely on assumptions or experimental results when writing threaded code. This never leads to anything good. In particular, if the library class is not documented to be thread-safe, it is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing and modifying a **non**-threadsafe class `LinkedList` from multiple threads. No, it's not safe. It may work for you in your tests, it may work in 99.9999% of cases, but it's still not safe.

One common issue with tests like these is that `System.out.println()` is synchronized ¹. This can cause tests to work when printing things, but fail when they're removed and there's no "accidental" synchronization happening that is affecting the code *you* are trying to test. This doesn't mean printing things makes code threadsafe, it's just a potential side effect.

> Testing thread safety can't be done reliably by running code multiple
>   times to see whether it works.

¹ Not to mention in this example the obvious memory effects of `CountDownLatch` and `Future.get()`. However the code is written in quite a complex way (especially for a demo) to make any claims about the thread safety of the actual running code.